# LNK1120 & LNK2019 Errors

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to learn SQLite3 API, when I debug fatal errors occur.
Known that i configured the linker to compile it as a console.

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CryptUnprotectData@28 referenced in function _main   ....\"filename".obj
>
> Error  2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   Debug\"filename".exe

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>


int  main()
    {


    sqlite3_initialize();
    sqlite3 *sqlHandle;
    int call;
    char *tail = NULL;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
    const FILE *fileHandle = "C:\\Users\\"username"\\Desktop\\Data.sqlite";
    call = sqlite3_open_v2(fileHandle, &sqlHandle, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,NULL);
    if (call != SQLITE_OK)
        {
        sqlite3_close(sqlHandle);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    //preparing statement to be executed
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlHandle, "SELECT action_url,username_value,password_value FROM logins", sizeof(char)*60, &stmt, &tail) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
        sqlite3_close(sqlHandle);
        printf("Can't retrieve data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlHandle));
        }


    CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB *blob;
    CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB *UnprotectedBlob = NULL;
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
        blob = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);
        if (CryptUnprotectData(blob, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, UnprotectedBlob))
            {
            printf("%s | %s | %s \n",
                sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0),
                sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1),
                UnprotectedBlob->cbData);
            }
        }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(sqlHandle);
    sqlite3_shutdown();
    _getch();
    return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link with the CryptoAPI library. You can do that either from the project properties for the linker (`Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Input` > `Additional dependencies`), or from code with a `#pragma` directive.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32")
```